# Rust modify item during iteration in BinaryHeap

Tags: rust

Currently the `BinaryHeap` in Rust does not provide an `iter_mut()` function like the `HashMap` does.  This is probably because the items in the `BinaryHeap` are ordered on the item values themselves and not a separate key.

Suppose I have a struct:

```
struct A {
    timestamp : u64,
    data : ...,
    ... : ...
}
```

such that `PartialEq`, `Eq`, `PartialOrd`, and `Ord` depend only on the `timestamp` field.

Modifying any other field would not require a reordering of the elements in the BinaryHeap.

Is there a better way to have the items in the `BinaryHeap` modified without having to copy them into a new `BinaryHeap`?

Initial ideas include storing just `timestamp` in the `BinaryHeap` and using a `HashMap` to store `timestamp -> data` but this results in maintenance of an additional data structure and doesn't automatically provide a good way for keying the `HashMap` (since a timestamp could appear more than once in the `BinaryHeap`)

Extending that idea, I could storing a wrapper object of `{ timestamp, id }` instead but then need to generate unique ids (counter?)

At this point, it seems like an overly complex solution...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RefCell` from ([`cell`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/) module) is probably something you should explore, it trumps the compile-time guarantees of ownership by inserting run-time guarantees instead.

So, if you have a generic `Key` and `Value`, you would create such a structure for `BinaryHeap`:

```
struct PartiallyMutable<Key, Value> {
    key: Key,
    value: RefCell<Value>,
}

impl<Key, Value> Eq for PartiallyMutable<Key, Value> where Key: Eq {
    fn eq(&self, &other: &Self) -> bool {
        self.key == other.key
    }
}

// etc...
```

And then using a `&PartiallyMutable<Key, Value>` you can actually modify the `value` field in place.